# USe Values from Gridview

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a web form to pull data from a sql database, populate a datatable and use that datatable to populate a Gridview.

The code for populating the GridView when the search button is pressed 
executes a Sql Query then sets the data Source to the datatable (GT1)

```
 GT1.Load(SCDR);
            EntryGrid.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
            EntryGrid.DataSource = GT1;
            EntryGrid.DataBind();
            EntryGrid.EditIndex = 0;
            EntryGrid.DataBind();
```

I was originally going to just use the gridview to populate a series of variables and use those to generate a Sql query, but `EntryGrid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text` produces an empty string.
[row.Cells[4].Text returns nothing in GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612377/row-cells4-text-returns-nothing-in-gridview1-selectedindexchanged) talks about using FindControl("control ID")  , but I just got more confused looking at this.  how do I find the control ID, and what exactly would I need to do to take a value from a specific cell in the gridview to a string variable?

The gridview is populated by the following code

```
DataTable GT1 = new DataTable();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string SqlQuery1 = sql.Replace("LASTNAME_", LastnameBox.Text);
        SqlQuery1 = SqlQuery1.Replace("LAST4_", PAsswordBox.Text);




        SqlConnection Conn1 = new SqlConnection(DC1.DbConn);
        Conn1.Open();
        SqlCommand SearchCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery1, Conn1);
        SqlDataReader SCDR = SearchCommand.ExecuteReader();


        GT1.Load(SCDR);
        EntryGrid.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
        EntryGrid.DataSource = GT1;
        EntryGrid.DataBind();
        EntryGrid.EditIndex = 0;
        EntryGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Control ID is the Id you set for your each of your items in the TemplateField. Here is an example of using the FindControl to get the information from a label and storing it in VarFromGrid. The row is grab by RowSelected. Not sure how you are wanting to get the row but that is one way to do it.

aspx code:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelGridViewBankName" runat="server" Text="something"></asp:Label>
```

code behind:

```
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
string VarFromGrid = row.Cells[4].FindControl('LabelGridViewBankName').Text;
```

EDIT:

You can use a GridViewRow to grab the row, then grab the data from it like below. You shouldn't need the find control.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)EntryGrid.SelectedItems[0];
string something = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Just remember to make sure the Grid row is not null or you'll get a null exception. And to close your connection string once done. I this still returns an empty string, take a look at your dataTable in debug mode and see how the data is being stored.

Comment: is 'LabelGridViewBankName' supposed to be the label on the column?   The gridview has the columns dynamically populated by the datatable it is using as a DataSource, and the dataTable has its Columns added when it does a DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader)

Comment: my latest attempt has me getting an error of 
'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you post some more of your code. Like where your grid is being created and your columns?

Comment: I updated the original post to reflect how the Gridview is populated.