# How to get the value of TableCell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I have a GridView that I am trying to dump into a csv file, but when I run my code the cell values are not output; my output file only consists of commas and newlines, without the cell values

I've done a bunch of google searching and I am trying to print out the values row by row, cell by cell, using a nested for loop:

```cs
String output = String.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
    GridViewRow currentRow = GridView1.Rows[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < currentRow.Cells.Count; j++) {
        output += (currentRow.Cells[j].Text + ",");
    }
    output += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Expected output should be a comma-separated list of values with multiple rows, but the file that is actually output looks similar to this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
etc
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you tried to debug it, and check that gridview actually contains cells with values when you trying to build an output?

Comment: Debugging produces ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n" and more commas ending with a newline are added at each breakpoint

Comment: That mean you gridview is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [row.Cells\[4\].Text returns nothing in GridView1\_SelectedIndexChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612377/row-cells4-text-returns-nothing-in-gridview1-selectedindexchanged)

Comment: Then how is the grid populated? I can see values in the app

Comment: Better use a library: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/